# Push the file in folder app on just updated in ubuntu web server

Tags: php, ubuntu, netbeans

I am using netbeans on windows to develop my php application. But, I use apache on ubuntu server as my web server because I want to develop a web app.

The problem is when I update the app. So, let's say I have updated the app which is a new one app's folder, I must delete the old app on ubuntu server in `/var/www/app`. Then I copy the new app using ssh to ubuntu server. It's not efficient.

How can I just push the file in folder app that changed on new app, 
What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Use an FTP/SFTP client like FileZilla.

[Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org)

Comment: Is it just change the file that updated or all of file

Comment: Only the file that was updated or, if you want, you can update/upload multiple files. It's up to you.